# object doesn't support this property or method (runtime error 438) using VBA to link to IE

Tags: html, excel, vba, object, runtime-error

```
Sub wpieautologin()
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim ObjCollection As Object
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
With ie
.Visible = True
.Navigate "website name"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until .ReadyState = 4
Set ObjCollection = .Document.getElementByID("ID").Value = "insert login 
ID"
```

I'm trying to enter login information to a website using VBA, but I'm getting this error message. I'm using excel 2016. Any ideas?

Error is on last line

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set ObjCollection = .Document.getElementByID("ID")
ObjCollection.Value = "insert login ID"
```

Comment: Literally was editing that as you posted. Still an error. If I remove the .value it works, but I need that to enter my login ID.

Comment: That's because you are instantiating an object. See edited answer.